# NonlinearModelFit code

Tags: nonlinear

I have the following code, but I don't know how to use the `NonlinearModelFit` code to fit the data to plot the Gaussian curve:

```
Ph = 0.5; 
N10 = 10;
bincoin10 = ListPlot[Table[{Nh,10*10*Ph^(Nh)*(1 - Ph)^(N10 - Nh)*N10!/((Nh!*(10-Nh)!))}, {Nh,0,10}]]
```

Comment: [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to assume that the table of 100 times the probability mass function of a binomial distribution could be considered appropriate data for use in `NonlinearModelFit`.  In other words the data really isn't in the form of

$$y=a*\exp[-(x-\mu)^2/v] + e$$

with $e\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.  You might consider the corresponding normal curve with the same mean and variance as the binomial:

```
x = Range[0, 10];
z = Range[0, 100]/10;
ListPlot[{Transpose[{x, 100 PDF[BinomialDistribution[N10, Ph], x]}],
  Transpose[{z, 100 PDF[NormalDistribution[N10 Ph, (N10 Ph (1 - Ph))^0.5], z]}]},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, Joined -> {False, True},
 PlotLegends -> {"100*Binomial[N10,Ph]",  "100*Corresponding normal density"}]
```

[image: Normal and binomial pdf times 100]

Comment: Thank you, The purpose of 100 was to adjust the Y axis to show the expected values rather than their probabilities.

Comment: Ok.  But the expected value for a count of x is `n*N10*Pr(X=x)` where `n` is the number of times that you sample from a binomial with parameters `N10` and `Ph`.  So you have `n=10`.  In other words without such an explicit definition it appears that the number 100 that you use comes out of nowhere.

Answer (score 3):

You should define the [`bincoin10`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/bincoin10.html) as a [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html), rather than [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html).

```
bincoin10 = 
  Table[{Nh, 
    10*10*Ph^(Nh)*(1 - Ph)^(N10 - Nh)*N10!/((Nh!*(10 - Nh)!))}, {Nh, 
    0, 10}];
```

Then you can simply use [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) with self-defined Gaussian function.

```
gauss = A 1/(σ Sqrt[2. π]) Exp[-(1./2.) ((x - μ)/σ)^2];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[bincoin10, gauss, {{σ, 1.}, {μ, 0}, {A, 25}}, x]
Show[ListPlot[bincoin10, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 2000}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Ph = 0.5;
N10 = 10;
bincoin10 = 
 ListPlot[Table[{Nh, 
    10*10*Ph^(Nh)*(1 - Ph)^(N10 - Nh)*N10!/((Nh!*(10 - Nh)!))}, {Nh, 
    0, 10}]]

data = Table[{Nh, 
10*10*Ph^(Nh)*(1 - Ph)^(N10 - Nh)*N10!/((Nh!*(10 - Nh)!))}, {Nh, 
0, 10}];

eq = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x]
```

> $0.0655594 x^4-1.31119 x^3+7.3208 x^2-7.6486 x+0.699301$

```
Plot[eq, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]